# Silverstripe Gridfield Relation

Tags: silverstripe

I am attempting to update the secure files silverstripe module to SS3.

In it, the author uses the following ComplexTableField:

```
    class SecureFileTokenPermissionDecorator extends DataExtension {
       static $has_many = array(
           'AccessTokens' => 'SecureFileAccessToken'
       );

    ....

    $tokenList = new ComplexTableField(
        $this->owner,
        'ContainedFileTokens',
        'SecureFileAccessToken',
        null,
        null,
        "File.ParentID = '{$this->owner->ID}'",
        $sourceSort = null,
        "JOIN File ON FileID = File.ID"
    ));
    $tokenList->setParentIdName('FolderID');
    $tokenList->setRelationAutoSetting(false);

    ....
    }
```

I was wondering how I would go about representing the same data/relation with gridfField.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [secure files](https://github.com/hamishcampbell/silverstripe-securefiles) module source code, I would suggest the following setup:

```
$tokenList = $gridField = new GridField(
    'AccessTokens', 
    'Tokens', 
    $this->owner->AccessTokens(), 
    GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()
);
```

This works directly on the relation getter, which is a lazy loaded list (not queried until necessary), and automatically paginated. I'm not quite sure how the `setParentIdName("FolderID")` fits in here, probably unnecessary. Caution: Haven't tried this on the actual codebase.

If you need some help understanding the API on a higher level, have a look in the [GridField docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/grid-field) and the ["datamodel" topic](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel).

Thanks for helping to make modules ready for SS3! :)